# Python - Convertion of GPS time to UTC

Tags: python, gps, utc, gps-time

I have been researching everywhere for a solution to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

I would like to take the time from the GPS data and need to convert that to a human readable format, may be like *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*.

Following is the GPS dataformat:

$GPRMC,***123519***,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,***230394***,003.1,W*6A

Here,
     *123519*   is    fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC and 
     *230394*   is the    date - 23rd of March 1994

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
for line in data.split('\n') :
    if line.startswith( '$GPRMC' ) :
        lat, _, lon = line.strip().split(',')[2:5]
```

to manually bring the string to a suitable format. Then pass this to `datetime.strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

Or use a library like

[pynmea2](https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2)

[micropyGPS](https://github.com/inmcm/micropyGPS)

Answer (score 0):

use gpsd service daemon
and then use code gpsd.utc

Comment: Hello, welcome to So! Could you explain your approach? Maybe put an example?